# Uninstalling a package completely including all log files

Tags: apt, package-management, uninstall

I use`sudo apt remove <package_name>` or `sudo apt purge --auto-remove <package_name>` to uninstall a package.
But this commands don't delete the files created by the package like "*.package_name*".
I want to know command lines that uninstall a package and delete all the files created by it.

Comment: Which files exactly do you want to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: "You can't".

There is no general way to remove all files a package produces - and for a good reason. If you install a web server and later remove it, you may want to keep the logs for analysis. If you install some office software and later replace it with a better one, you definitely don't want to get rid of all the documents you authored.

Short - not very exact - description of your `apt` command's elements:

- `apt remove PACKAGE` – deinstalls PACKAGE's binaries
- `apt purge PACKAGE` – removes the above plus config files that came with PACKAGE
- `apt autoremove` – removes any packages that were once needed but are not any more - like old kernels or depencencies of uninstalled software